# What are the main differences between a Live and Dev network?

Tags: live-network

I kinda know there are differences between both types, such as cli flags --ws, --rpc, --dev (which include many other flags for development), chain spec file, ports, and so on.

What are the main differences between live network vs dev network using Substrate? If I want to deploy a private network in production, what is essential to know?

Answer (score 2):

I only found two differences.

Check [this](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/client/cli/src/params/network_params.rs#L197-L209).

You could global search the keywords `ChainType::Live`, `ChainType::Development` in Substrate repository.

Answer (score 0):

In order to help people who still have some doubts about this topic, I bring you some interesting information about the subject, especially for new Substrate Devs.

Besides the mentioned change from ChainType::Dev or Local to ChainType::Live in terms of network type, there are many other things to consider, such as the use of development accounts with predefined balances when accessing the network. Depending on the configuration, it may require a certain number of nodes to produce blocks, whereas in dev mode it may be possible to create a network with a single node that produces and finalizes blocks. Additionally, the entire deployment process comes into play, including choosing the type of node that will be created (RPC node, Archive, Full, etc). There are many other flags that can be set, which will determine the behavior of a specific node. There is also the question of how the logging and telemetry data of that node will be handled. Another point of consideration is the use of Docker, whether to deploy the service within a Kubernetes cluster or in a VM.

Many of these items mentioned here were added after I asked the question in the official Substrate documentation. Here is the link for more information on how to deploy and further differences between a dev network and a production network: https://docs.substrate.io/deploy/